# Haskell function that prints a randomly generated trace for a nondeterministic transition system

Tags: haskell, trace, transition-systems

I'm having problems with getting the random number generator to work and i am not sure why. I have to do this in a lab for school and the program is supposed to print the trace of a non deterministic transition system by choosing the next state at random. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

import System.Random (StdGen)
import qualified System.Random as Random

rngTrace :: Int -> TrSys a -> a -> [a]
rngTrace r tr c =
      c : List.unfoldr next c
    where
      next c =
        let cs = tr c in
         if null cs then Nothing else Just (Set.elemAt s cs, Set.elemAt s cs )
          where
            s:ss = Random.randomRs (0, Set.size (tr c) ) (Random.mkStdGen r)
```

Comment: What is the error message or can you explain the problems in more detail?

Comment: Well, one red flag right off the bat is that `ss` is not used anywhere.

Comment: For this task, `unfoldr next c` looks hard to use, if not impossible since it will deterministically generate a list depending on `c` alone (roughly). This approach could be improved by pairing the current state of the RNG with `c`, so that `next` can access both the current state and the RNG state, and return 1) the next value in the list, 2) the next state, and 3) the next RNG state. In this way the RNG state is also updated, so that we can really sample new random data at each step.